# Make changes to contacts 

Tags: android, contacts

I'm making android app that tells you the operator's name of your contact's number.

Is there a way to put a label containing the name of the operator next to every number directly in the contacts list?

Comment: My novice guess is you'd need to rewrite the stock contacts provider with an additional field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own sync provider and your own RawContacts table. Fill it up with name, phone number and the data you need (e.g., the operator name). Not an easy. task There's a very nice post with lots of details here:

http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/

http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/

There's an example in the android Technical Resources pages: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

Comment: do u mean it will be quite simpler to make my own phonebook app??? tnx a lot for your reply